# URL pattern in message

Tags: django, django-views, django-messages

After the register, I would like to display a message with a link inside. The link should go to the login form: membres.views.login. I've read something about reverse url but did not really understand it...

And of course it does not work.

Error:

```
name 'membres' is not defined
```

views.py:

```
messages.success(request, 'Votre inscription est désormais terminée. <a href="' + reverse(membres.views.login) + '">Connectez-vous</a> pour démarrer l'aventure.')
```

Any idea? Need more code? My message is inside my def register(request).

Thanks

Comment: Use `reverse('membres.views.login')`

Comment: Damned, I always am very close to the solution but do some dumb mistakes. That works perfectly. Thanks